# Controller inside ion-nav-buttons fired twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, controller

I need a controller inside the ion-nav-buttons to display badges based on need. But the controller inside the ion-nav-buttons is fired twice, whereas it works smoothly if I put it outside the ion-nav-buttons.

Example: http://play.ionic.io/app/a8f23a5bc384

**HTML content**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar bg-main">
            <ion-nav-back-button style="color: #fff">
                </ion-nav-back-button>
                <ion-nav-back-button style="color: #fff">
                </ion-nav-back-button>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                    <a ng-href="#/notification" class="button" ng-controller="NotifyCtrl">
                    </a>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view name="" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

    </ion-side-menus>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).
controller('NotifyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  alert();
}]);
```

Posted the question n ionic forum with no much help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u inspect and see the entire dom is replicated twice so its calling twice

Move your ng-controller="NotifyCtrl"and passte inside ion-side-menus

```
 <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true"  ng-controller="NotifyCtrl">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar bg-main">
            <ion-nav-back-button style="color: #fff">
                </ion-nav-back-button>
                <ion-nav-back-button style="color: #fff">
                </ion-nav-back-button>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                    <a ng-href="#/notification" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-bell-outline">
                    </a>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view name="" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

    </ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: It does work as you suggested. But is there any reason it 'ion-nav-buttons' behavior? What if I wanted a different controller within 'ion-nav-buttons'?